# Does Red Buff stack and how long does it last?

Tags: teamfight-tactics

If I have 2 does it apply 5% burn? How long does it last, and how fast is each tick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ticks, from experience, seem to be one per second and I think last until end of fight.

Also, seeing how every other item seems to stack (if you have 2, the effect is done twice, like having 2 spears of shoujin on a character makes it pretty much ult over and over) I would say it straight up does it twice.

So it does a 2.5% burn, then another 2.5% burn. So if there's no weird math, that gives a 5% burn.

Comment: The base burn is 2.5% IIRC

Comment: I tought while writing my answer that 'Damn, 5% is broken AF'. Rereading the question yeah, he meant both together are 5%, not 5% each. :p